# How to combine keydown.control with a custom click function in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to select *multiple* number elements in random order and store them to an array by *pressing down* the `control key (CTRL)` and *clicking* the element, e.g. 2 and 4 from 5? After many attempts I was not able to combine the click event with `@Hostlistener`.

[image]

```
<div class="nums">
   <div *ngFor="let tempNum of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]">
      <span class="num" (click)="onNumClick(tempNum)">{{ tempNum }}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
@Hostlistener('window.keydown.control', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
   console.log('Control key clicked');
}

onNumClick(num: number) {
   this.selectedNums.push(num);
}
```

Comment: You mean onNumClick should only do something when the user holds down the CTRL key while clicking? Is that it?

Comment: Hi chris, I mean both: you can click one day or hold down CTRL key for more days while clicking. If not possible, then only the latter.

Comment: You should just check if control is down when you click, not listen for ctrl. check [e.ctrlKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really simple solution would be something like this - just check if the click event has the `ctrlKey` flag set, and modify behavior accordingly.

```html
<div class="nums">
  <div *ngFor="let num of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]">
      <span class="num" 
      (click)="select(num, $event.ctrlKey)">{{ num }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I'm using `Set` instead of an array to easily avoid duplicates.

```js
readonly selectedNums = new Set<number>();

select(num: number, selectMulti: boolean): void {
    if (!selectMulti) {
        this.selectedNums.clear();
    }
    this.selectedNums.add(num);
}
```

Remember that this obviously won't be usable on mobile devices. For mobile users you'll have to offer an alternative, such as checkboxes or longpress.

Comment: Great reminder that this approach is not mobile friendly!